# Using phone layout for multiple screens

Tags: android

I`m trying to publish my app on`Google Play Store` with the layout I set for my 5" phone and it always says that app is not prepared for tablets. I just want my app to be displayed on every device without have to redefine layouts for each screen. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can use different layout and save it in layout-large or layout-xlarge with this same name.

Comment: I just copy the xml files in layout folder to layout-large and layout-xlarge and it keeps saying the the apk is not prepared for tablets.

Comment: Maybe this link can help: 
https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use different layout and save it in layout-large or layout-xlarge with this same name.

See this from documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I just copy the xml files in layout folder to layout-large and layout-xlarge and it keeps saying the the apk is not prepared for tablets.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your application to be available to phone as well as tablet devices, you can declare the element in your manifest like this:

`<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                   android:normalScreens="true"
                   android:largeScreens="true"
                   android:xlargeScreens="true" />`

You can find more details in the following link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: I've declared these elements in the manifest file, although when I upload the apk it still says that it's not prepared for tablets.

Comment: Can you post your manifest file ?  It will help to identify the issue